# Lightbend examples syntax error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, slick

I just wonder if I have messed something up or is it just unavoidable pain of using Scala. I wanted to test out slick so I decided to run `activator-play-slick-angularjs` example from `Lightbend`. Unfortunatelly I get syntax errors while using

`lazy protected val empTableQuery: TableQuery[EmployeeTable] = TableQuery[EmployeeTable]`

in any possible way. In filtering examples, the type I am required by Scala plugin to use is `Any` e. g.

`def delete(id: Int): Future[Int] = db.run { empTableQuery.filter(_.id === id).delete }`

`_.id` part yields syntax error. I bet that I am just missing something because I can't imagine a single developer willing to work in 2017 without syntax assistance from IDE.

Comment: does the application compile in sbt?

Comment: @rogue-one yes, it do compile

Comment: is the IDE complaining about this line.?
`lazy protected val empTableQuery: TableQuery[EmployeeTable] = TableQuery[EmployeeTable]`
if your empTableQuery is properly assigned the type `TableQuery[EmployeeTable] ` you would not be having this issue.

Comment: @rogue-one IDE is not complaining about this line. Its more like id is inaccessible for some strange reason when referring to EmployeeTable

Comment: @rogue-one AHHH, thanks for help my friend. Your words that it should be working made my brain look closer at the code. The EmployeeTable class is defined with private[EmployeeTable]. This is the reason why isn't it visible in EmployeeRepository class I bet. After having deleted the private statement IDE started to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody met this problem in future - in this example `EmployeeTable` is defined with `private[EmployeeTable]` what makes in not visible in `EmployeeRepository` class. Just skip the `private[EmployeeTable]` part in class definition to make everything work smoothly.